# Can I use push notifications without developing my own server?

Tags: android, push-notification, server

I want to make android app, which will use `push notifications`, but I don't know how to create my own server (I don't know `php`). Can I create this application using some free services?

Comment: It is possible using toolkits like Parse. However Facebook has announced that Parse services will terminate next year. check out any alternatives.

Comment: you can use **https://www.pushwoosh.com**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Parse Push](https://parse.com). But their services will only be available until Jan 2017. But you can try http://rzlts.com/. It's a free straight forward tool.

Comment: Of course. There are multiple tools you can play with. Give them a try and use the simplest one which suits your need